How to solve a final pb when merging a series of .ts file with concat command of FFmpeg?
I had dowloaded some videos from the Internet, feaw years ago…
I obtained many files: a series of files in .ts
In my example: a series of 306 files named from segment1_4_av.ts to segment306_4_av.ts
A command line to merge the aforementioned files appears to be:
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy all.ts
To obtain mylist.txt, two methods are suggested:

for Windows Powershell:
foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem .*.ts) {"file '$i'" | Out-File mylist.txt -Encoding utf8 -Append}

or for Windows bat-file:
(for %%i in (*.ts) do @echo file '%%i') > mylist.txt


24/06/2024:
[PB resolved]
In mylist.txt, the result is not in the  order :
file 'segment100_1_av.ts'
file 'segment101_1_av.ts'
file 'segment102_1_av.ts'
file 'segment103_1_av.ts'
file 'segment104_1_av.ts'
file 'segment105_1_av.ts'
file 'segment106_1_av.ts'
file 'segment107_1_av.ts'
file 'segment108_1_av.ts'
file 'segment109_1_av.ts'
file 'segment10_1_av.ts'
file 'segment110_1_av.ts'
file 'segment111_1_av.ts'
file 'segment112_1_av.ts'
file 'segment113_1_av.ts'
file 'segment114_1_av.ts'
file 'segment115_1_av.ts'
file 'segment116_1_av.ts'
file 'segment117_1_av.ts'
file 'segment118_1_av.ts'
file 'segment119_1_av.ts'
file 'segment11_1_av.ts'
…
Due to the lack of zeros in the .ts file names:
I read :
This is fixed by using leading zeros:
for %i in (?.ts) do ren %i 000%i
for %i in (??.ts) do ren %i 00%i
for %i in (???.ts) do ren %i 0%i
I tried to copy these three lines in a .bat file placed in the folder where all my .ts files are… but when I run this .bat file : nothing appens!
Could you help me to rename the .ts files? (in order to concatenate them in a second time).
Thanks ;-)
25/06/2024:
[PB resolved, but using a alternative way… (with playlist)]
I succeded to add leading zeros, and to creat (apparently) correct mylist.txt:

With Advanced Renamer soft, I renamed my series of files:
segment1_4_av.ts … segment306_4_av.ts
in: 1.ts … 306.ts

With Powershell command (as administrator):
Get-ChildItem star.star | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.PadLeft(3+(".ts".length),'0')}


the leading zeros are correctly added
(source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FttMJpQQX9Y)

With Powershell command:
foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem .*.ts) {"file '$i'" | Out-File mylist.txt -Encoding utf8 -Append}

the correct mylist.txt seems to be created…


But, in final concatanation:
PS C:\vid> ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.ts

(all my .ts files and mylist.txt file are in "vid" folder)
the process fails:

Please, thanks for help :-)
26/06/2024:
Two contributors gave me ideas to solve the problem.
It seems that these two solutions point the excact path to success :
I) pjc50 :
"Remove the BOM from the .txt file, then try again."
-> I tried the link (where the process is very well explained):
https://docs.tamr.com/tamr-help-center/docs/error-in-uploading-utf-8-with-bom

II) Ricardo Bohner :
"Try saving the myfiles.txt file as ANSI, in notepad, File menu, save as..."
III) Independently, I tried an other technique to creat mylist.txt:
a Windows bat-file:
(for %%i in (*.ts) do @echo file '%%i') > mylist.txt
→ Result of these I), II) and III) methods:
a file output.ts is created (with the three methods), but:
A) a new problem appeared during operation :

with method I:


with method II:



with method III: idem


B) Once the operation is finished:
when I play the video out.ts (with VLC), the result is not perfect: there are, often, like "jumbs", or "breaks" (I don't find the correct word…) on the video (not on the audio)…
I imagine this pb on out.ts is a result of the problem described in paragraphe A), just above…
Please, would you have a explanation for this problem described in paragraphe A)?
27/06/2024:
pjc50 explained to me:

"it's getting extremely complicated now."
And he suggested: "To get the alternative approach of assembling a playlist."

Actually, I had recently, and at the same time,  posted a question about playlist here:
What a correct playlist.m3u8 should contain, or should look like?
And a contributor gave me the solution to my question, on the correct playlist to concatenate.
So indeed, thanks to this alternative technique, I am now able to obtain the result that I was looking for.
So it's OK, for me the goal is achieved :-)
Thank You very much to different contributors, who gave me the solution!
NB: Sources:
merge/join/concatenate hundreds of ts files into one ts file
Program to join TS videos using command line
how to join ts files together into mp4 with ffmpeg?
Use ffmpeg copy codec to combine *.ts files into a single mp4
From m3u8/ts files to mp4
Windows 7 command to add a leading zero to a batch of filenames
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate
PS:
I have Win 10

Try saving the myfiles.txt file as as ANSI, in notepad, File menu, save as....

@Ricardo Bohner: Thank you very much, your proposition succeeded… But a new problem has appeard afterwards (see my post of 26/06/2024).

It looks like windows has given you one final hurdle. Note the error message says "unknown keyword ' file'". See the initial space? That space can't be seen in notepad when looking at "mylist.txt". That suggests a Unicode BOM (byte order mark). These tend to trip up programs that aren't expecting them.
Try https://docs.tamr.com/tamr-help-center/docs/error-in-uploading-utf-8-with-bom or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52272705/batch-script-remove-bom-%C3%AF-from-file techniques to remove the BOM from the .txt file, then try again.

@ pjc: Thank you very much for your help, your proposition has perfectly succeeded… But a new problem has appeard afterwards (see my post dated of 26/06/2024).

@dglr getting extremely complicated now. https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20820/h264-omx-and-non-existing-pps-0-referenced ; did you ever get the alternative approach of assembling a playlist to work?

@ pjc: You are right, thanks to playlist, I succeded ;-) However, I don't understand why the method used in this post fails, while "ffmpeg -i playlist.m3u -codec copy output.mkv" succeeds??? Is-it because the output file is in .mkv, and not in .ts ?

@dglr quite likely because of the output format, yes; the messages are complaining about a missing frame zero. I don't fully understand it either but I suspect that putting it in a container forces ffmpeg to regenerate the overall stream info (size etc) and zero frame

@ pjc: By curiosity, I have just tried the command line: ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mkv Whe obtain similar messages [h264 @ 000001fe840292c0] decode_slice_header error [h264 @ 000001fe840292c0] no frame! [h264 @ 000001fe840292c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced. But the output.mkv file don't seem perfect but very better quality comparing precedent output.ts file. JayCravens, I am grateful for the help you gave me. Thank you so much.
